# How can I get Xcode to support tabs over the jump bar?

Tags: xcode

I selected View -> Tab Bar to enable tabs in Xcode.

However, when I open a new file, it appears in the jump bar below the single existing tab and not as a new tab.

How do I get new files to appear as new tabs in Xcode? I've been spending some time trying different things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double clicking your source files in the Navigator pane should make them appear in new tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to create new tabs. Then on whatever tab is active a single click on source files sets its context.